# Kubernetes: How to update namespace without changing external IP address?

Tags: kubernetes

How to update namespace without changing External-IP of the Service?

Initially, it was without namespace and it was deployed:

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: my-app
```

It creates External-IP address and it was pointed to the DNS. Now I would like to update the Namespace to keep it more organised. So I have created the namespace.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: my-namespace
```

and I have updated the service with a namespace.

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app
  namespace: my-namespace
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: my-app
```

The above file creates another Service in `my-namespace` and the External-IP is not the same. Is there a way to update the namespace without recreating?

Please let me know if you need any information. Thanks!

Comment: Which cloud provider are you using, if any?

Comment: @PaulAnnetts Azure's AKS

Answer (score 3):

some cloud providers allow you to specify external ip of a service with https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#external-ips if you can ake use of this, you should be able to achieve what you need. This will not be a zero downtime operation though as you'll first need to delete the current service and recreate it under different namespace with externalIP specified.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that what you are after is a static public IP address, that is, one that you have reserved and outlives your cluster. If you had one of these, you would be able to specify it for your `LoadBalancer` either as @Radek mentions above, or possibly with a provider-specific annotation. Then you would be able to move the IP address between `LoadBalancer`s (same applies for `Ingress` too).

However it seems you have not yet allocated a static public IP yet. It may be a good time to do this, but as Azure doesn’t appear to allow you to “promote” a dynamic IP to a static IP it won’t directly help you here (*).

So you’re left with creating a new `LoadBalancer` resource with a new public IP. To aid transition and avoid downtime, you could use an external DNS entry to switch users over from 1st to 2nd LoadBalancer IP addresses, which can be done seamlessless and without downtime if you set things up correctly. However does take a bit of time to transition: only once the DNS TTL period is done, is it safe to delete the first `LoadBalancer`.

If you don’t have an external DNS, this illustrates why it’s a good idea to set it up.

(*) GCP does allow you to do this, I doubt AWS does.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to address this issue is to introduce nginx ingress controller. Let Externel LB route the calls to ingress controller. just update the ingress rules with correct service mapping.

the advantage is that you can expose any number of apps/service from single external IP via ingress. Without ingress you will have to setup one external LB for each application/service that you want to expose to outside world

Comment: There are other ways of doing this e.g. Istio. Depending on cloud provider Nginx Ingress may not be best choice either.

Comment: we use ingress controller it our environment and it works well for us. there is no need to vote it down. if you have a better way to do, post your answer

Comment: However this question is about `LoadBalancer` not `Ingress` - I don't think the OP is asking for advice about that. I don't know enough information about the OP situation to be able to answer, or to know if the other answer will solve the problem.